# What is '!!' and '::' functions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling to google search what the '::' and what the '!!' do within the Dplyr package or R in general. ( I am very new to R).

```
    dplyr::select(Level, Effect) %>%
    rename(!!colname := Effect,
           !!effect := Level)
```

Comment: Please enter `?\`::\`` and `?\`!!\`` in your R console.

Comment: `::` is used to specify a function from a package. `dplyr::select` means "the `select` function from the `dplyr` package". It's sometimes necessary to use `::` if you have 2 (or more) packages loaded that use the same function name for different functions.

Comment: `!!` and `:=` are a little more complicated, I'd suggest reading [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to get a strong intro to them.